# Mysterious Segfault

Tags: assembly, segmentation-fault

I'm getting a segmentation fault I can't figure out when trying to call a varargs function. In debuggers (both Nemiver/GDB and [EDB](https://github.com/eteran/edb-debugger)), the faulty instruction is `movaps xmmword ptr [rbp-288], xmm7` and `rbp == 0x00007ffd0e16ba78`, which is on the stack. `xmm7` is `0`, if it matters.

The instruction is at `.text:00401d10`, in the `buffer_appendf` function.

[Online Disassembler](https://www.onlinedisassembler.com/odaweb/9AL1qfGW/0)

[Binary Download](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/63823144/stage2)

Comment: That probably means you messed up stack alignment. `movaps` requires 16 byte alignment of the operand, and most calling conventions ensure that.

Comment: Because the x86 stack grows down, can I just `and rsp 0xff...f0` to ensure 16-byte alignment, assuming I *can* guarantee that the stack has 8-bit alignment?

Comment: Yes but the root cause is that you actually messed up the alignment somewhere earlier. Sure, you can fix the alignment at the fault but that's the wrong solution. Looks like the culprit is `parallisp_main`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`movaps` requires 16 byte alignment of the operand, and most calling conventions ensure that. The root cause is that you actually messed up the alignment somewhere earlier, by the look of it it's `parallisp_main`:

```
0x0000000000400a95 <+159>:  pop    %rbx
0x0000000000400a96 <+160>:  callq  *%rax
0x0000000000400a98 <+162>:  callq  0x4007e0 <free@plt>
0x0000000000400a9d <+167>:  retq
```

Moving the `pop %rbx` to just before the `retq` should fix the alignment.